# Propper configuration of Android Studio on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, adb

I was thinking that I did a proper installation of Android Studio on Ubuntu, but now I need to run the `adb install` it says:

```
The program 'adb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:  
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

The thing is that I have `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` on my computer, and I assume that if I make a `sudo apt-get install` will install another copy of it.

What can I do to run my `adb` or to fix the problem?

ps: I'm new to programming & ubuntu :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was way to easy :"( ./adb is one.

Anyway, I decided to use the nvidia [Tegra Android Development Pack](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack) which does the entire process so much easy to handle